# SQL Server SPID/hostname

Tags: sql-server

I have kill spid, I need to know what userID and hostname of the spid which I kill

Thanks

Comment: If you killed it, that connection doesn't exist anymore. Perhaps you should look at [sp_who2](http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/sp_who2%20-%20filtering%20and%20sorting%20the%20results.aspx) which is an undocumented version of [sp_who](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-who-transact-sql) or [Adam Mechanic's Better Version](http://whoisactive.com/)

Comment: I was thinking if there is way you can retrive history of the spid